# value from main query is used by the subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc

```
SELECT 
   userid, lastname, firstname , (SELECT COUNT(day) FROM PROFILE WHERE userid = ?) as numday
FROM PROFILE
```

I want to get each user's number of days present in the PROFILE table but Im confused of what value should I place in the question mark (?) in the query.

Please help...

Comment: You need to use `JOIN`, update the question and add the DDL for both tables.

Comment: Suppose it is in the same table, what will the query look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT 
   userid, lastname, firstname ,
  (SELECT COUNT(day) FROM PROFILE WHERE userid = P.userid) as numday
FROM PROFILE P
```

**Updated:** using `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT userid, lastname, firstname, COUNT(day) as numday
FROM PROFILE
GROUP BY userid, lastname, firstname
```

Comment: Yeah! It worked, but it takes 2 minutes before I get the result. What is happening? Any Idea?

Comment: I do have a lot of data, that's why it takes sometimes to get the result, but thank you..

Answer (score 0):

Try this untested query:

```
SELECT 
   userid, lastname, firstname , numday
FROM PROFILE as p join (SELECT COUNT(day) as numday, userid FROM DTR group by userid ) as q on p.userid = q.userid
```